# Passing a method to an ExceptionFilterAttribute in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI application where I've implemented an Exception Handling action filter that derives from ExceptionFilterAttribute, which I apply at the Action level. Simplified version:

```
    public class ExceptionHandlingAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
       Action cleanUp;
       public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
       {
           // ...

           if (cleanUp != null)
           {
                cleanUp();
           }

        }
    }

    // On Action
    [ExceptionHandlingAttribute(cleanUp = () => { // do something.. })]
    public SomeModel Foo(SomeModel input) {}
```

I want an action to be able to pass a function (Func or Action) to be executed (like cleanUp above) in the Action Filter. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I've edited my post with an example using the class structure you provided above, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not be able to do this with attributes unfortunately. Parameters passed into an attributes are only allowed to be any of the following, pulled from the C# spec:

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class
>   are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int,
>   long, short, string.
>
> The type object.
>
> The type System.Type.
>
> An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in
>   which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility (Section
>   17.2).
>
> Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

As a followup, you do have other options. For example, you could pass it the type of a class that's meant to house your cleanup functions, as well as the name of the function as a string constant. You would then have enough information to use reflection to instantiate the type and call the method as needed.

Here's an example:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
     private readonly Type _type;
     private readonly string _method;
     public ExceptionHandlingAttribute(Type type, string method){ _type = type; _method = method; }
     public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
     {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
        var method = _type.GetMethod(_method);
        var result = method.Invoke(instance);
        //process result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that does what I need.

Comment: I don't necessarily recommend this approach, using attributes to execute code can very quickly turn into a hot mess.